# Number of relations and number of functions on an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{$ Relations which are not functions from $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R\}$ and

$B = \{$ Functions from $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R\}$

How do I compare their cardinalities? I think there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$, but I'm not sure how to explicitly write it.

Answer (score 2):

Given a relation $R\in A$ — that is, $R\subseteq \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ — there are two ways $R$ can fail to be a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$:

(i) The domain of $R$ is not all of $\Bbb R$: $dom(R) = \{x\mid \exists y\, (x,y)\in R\} \ne \Bbb R$, or

(ii) $dom(R)$ is all of $\Bbb R$ but $R$ is not single-valued.

Notice that $A'$ $:=$ the set of of all relations on $\Bbb R_+$ is contained in (i). The cardinality of $A'$ is
$$\begin{align}
\lvert A'\rvert &= \lvert\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R_+\times\Bbb R_+)\rvert \\
&= 2^{\lvert \Bbb R_+\times\Bbb R_+\rvert} \\
&= 2^{\lvert \Bbb R_+ \rvert\cdot\lvert\Bbb R_+\rvert} \\
&= 2^{\lvert \Bbb R_+ \rvert}\tag{$\kappa^2=\kappa$ for infinite $\kappa$} \\
&= 2^{\lvert \Bbb R \rvert} \tag{$\lvert \Bbb R_+ \rvert = \lvert \Bbb R \rvert$}. \\
\end{align}$$
Clearly $|A'|\le |A|$, so $2^{\lvert \Bbb R \rvert} \le |A|$. However, a computation similar to the above shows that the cardinality of the set of all relations on $\Bbb R$ is $2^{\lvert \Bbb R \rvert}$, and as that set contains $A$, we get $|A|\le 2^{\lvert \Bbb R \rvert}$. So 
$$|A| = 2^{\lvert \Bbb R \rvert}.$$

For the cardinality of $B$, note that if $\kappa$ is infinite then $2^{\kappa} \le \kappa^{\kappa} \le (2^{\kappa})^{\kappa} = 2^{\kappa\cdot \kappa} = 2^{\kappa}$, so $\kappa^{\kappa} = 2^{\kappa}$. Thus the cardinality of $B$ is
$$
\lvert B \rvert = 2^{\lvert \Bbb R \rvert}.
$$

($A,B$ have the same cardinality.)